# one page site module with sticky menu

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm using the [one page site](https://www.drupal.org/project/single_page_site) module to make a one page design website. When scroll down, I want the menu to mode up to the top of the screen and get sticky there. I found some solutions for that, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496240/how-can-i-stick-the-div-after-scrolling-down-a-little).

The problem is that when I include jquery library link to my `page.tpl.php` to make the sticky menu script work, the [one page site](https://www.drupal.org/project/single_page_site) module doesn't work anymore. This module depends on the [jquery update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module. How can I combine the [one page site](https://www.drupal.org/project/single_page_site) module with a jquery sticky menu?

Thanks!
Steven

Comment: you don't need another copy of jquery library in page.tpl.php if you're using jquery_update

Comment: But with jquery_update alone the sticky menu script I mentioned above doesn't work at all

Comment: The script is likely incompatible with the version of jQuery then @Steven. There's nothing Drupal can do to help you with that, you'll need to rewrite the menu script, or lower your version of jQuery

Comment: That sticky header jquery looks absolutely generic and should work with any jQuery provided by jquery_update module.

Comment: I see that the single page site generates other js files which are loaded in the head section of the HTML output (e.g. sites/all/modules/single_page_site/lib/jquery-scrollspy.js, sites/all/modules/single_page_site/js/single-page-site-scrollspy.js and sites/all/modules/single_page_site/js/single-page-site-scroll.js). Is it possible that these .js files overrule the sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js?v=1.8.3 file? Because if I include this last file again in my page.tpl.php, the scroll function works again, but the single page site module doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I contacted the maintainer of the Single Page Site module. When scrolling down, a .fixed CSS class is added to the markup when the menu disappears. So it's very easy to add the CSS to obtain the sticky menu.